# C++, Visual-Studio: Is it possible to create an executable that would set up enviroment variables and than execute?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, environment-variables

For my programm to run I need system variable defited. I vant to be capable to set it and restart my app immidiatly or, if it is set do nothing. how to create such app with visual studio C++?

Comment: Hard to see why you have to restart your app.  Just continue with what you'd normally do if the environment variables were already set.

Comment: @Hans Passant some of the dlls I use require sertan paths to be defined as enviromental variables.

Comment: Well, that's fine.  It can only bomb if they use these environment variables before you set them.  Set them early, first thing you do in main().

Answer (score 2):

Use a wrapper application that sets the environment variable, then launches the main app.

Answer (score 1):

Does [`SetEnvironmentVariable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686206.aspx) work?

Comment: @Kabumbus: [`RegisterApplicationRestart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373347.aspx)

Comment: @Kabumbus: Obviously not, as the page says. :P You'd need a separate program (or the same program which behaves differently with a different argument) on XP.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not clear why the "restart" is necessary. The application can decide what to do based on whether environment variable is set or not, and it can also set it (`SetEnvironmentVariable`). Of course, you can always create a new process (`CreateProcess`) with your application name and end the current process, but something smells wrong with this design.